# Fluent NHibernate API and .NET 2.0

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, .net-2.0

Can I use Fluent NHibernate API for .NET 2.0 applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, FluentNhibernate requires .NET 3.5