# Generating db schema from c# class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, schema, database

Is there any other method than nHibernate by wich we can generate db schema from class definition? My classes arn't that complex etc (few one-to-many relations). However I would like  to just be able to save my objects in db and recreate schema if needed.
I am stuck with .NET 2.0. I am not that particular about performance for this project, I am just lazy to create tables and write save/load code and deel with nHibernate xml.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure to accept answers to your questions by clicking the checkmark beside the answer that helped you resolve the issue.  It gives you rep, and makes your questions *much* more desirable to answer.

Comment: Wow, despite people giving you correct answers you haven't taken the time to mark any of them as accepted! Do you think you can break that trend sometime soon?

Answer (score 2):

.NET classes are not compatible with a relational data model. That's why ORMs such as NHibernate exist. Without a mapping which describes the conversion of the model to relational tables you cannot create a DB schema. You could take a look at [FluentNhibernate automapping](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping) feature. If you stick to the conventions it can create the database schema from .NET classes.

Comment: according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428151/fluent-nhibernate-api-and-net-2-0
.NET 3.5 is required for fluent nhibernate.

Comment: This isn't correct. Automapping allows you to use conventions to avoid creating mapping files, it has nothing to do with schema generation.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate can do this. The relevant classes -- SchemaExport and SchemaUpdate -- are in the NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl namespace. Here's [one example](http://www.acceptedeclectic.com/2007/11/nhibernatehow-to-build-great-mappings.html).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, ther are other ways. THis is called "programming" - you may have heard of that. Basically, it is possible to write your own database generator. Been there, done that, long before nhibernate had that functionality (or, actually, even existed).

Sit down, write your own database generator.